# can't update npm (missing access)

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

Breaking my head to get over that error. I've tried every forum but still I can't find a proper solution. I also uninstalled and reinstall npm and still same issue.

Please save me!

npm error

[image]

and also

log

[image]

ta!

Comment: error is self explained. Write permission error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a wild guess:

- remove .npm-modules in your home folder
- remove modules from the project you are using
- npm install, all should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Use `homebrew` to install npm and nodejs. Write the command as shown below:

`brew install node` . Once it is successfully installed check it with `node -v`.

For more details you can go through this [tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-mac)

Comment: Still the same.